# How to subtract hours and minutes from each other in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two fields `dateTS` and  `closingTime`.

- `dateTS` is a normal timestamp field (e.g. 2019-07-13 22:31:10.000000)
- `closingTime` is a HH:MM format of when a store closes (e.g. 23:00)

I need a PostgreSQL query to subtract the two field and get the number of minutes difference between them.

Using the examples given above the difference between the two fields would be 28 minutes

So far I've tried different variations of the datediff function, but it won't work.

My guess is I either have to

- a. generate a fake timestamp for `closingTime` which is the same day as the `dateTs` field and subtract the 2 timestamps.

or

- b. convert the hour/minutes of both field to a float and subtract the two values to get the hours difference and convert that to minutes

Answer (score 1):

You can just [subtract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) them by converting the timestamp to a time:

```
select closingtime - datets::time
from your_table;
```

That will give you an [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) as the result.

To convert that to minutes you can get the number of seconds and divide it by 60:

```
select (extract epoch from closingtime - datets::time) / 60
from your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast your closing time to an interval and the timestamp to time and then subtract the two. By casting the timestamp to time you are effectively discarding the date part. You can the subtract one from the other to generate the difference as an interval.

```
select closingTime::interval - dateTS::time...
```

e.g.:

```
# select '23:00'::interval - now()::time;
    ?column?
-----------------
 05:31:00.031141
(1 row)
```

If needed you can then convert the interval to minutes:

```
# select extract(epoch from ('23:00'::interval - now()::time)) / 60;
     ?column?
------------------
 327.435313083333
(1 row)
```

Comment: Weird, I am getting this redshift error when selecting `dateTS::time`: 
[0A000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.; 

Anyways, I've used the substring function on `dateTS` to get the HH:MM and used interval instead and now it works!

`extract(epoch from (closingTime::interval-substring(dateTS,12,5)::interval))/60`